# Is Interlocked.Decrement(i) right for Parallel.ForEach()?

Tags: c#, multithreading, parallel-processing

In the past I have done this:

```
List<Item> _Items = GetItems();
int _CountDown = _Items.Count;
using (BackgroundWorker _Worker = new BackgroundWorker())
{
    _Worker.DoWork += (s, arg) =>
    {
        DoSomething(_Items[_CountDown]);
    };
    _Worker.RunWorkerCompleted += (s, arg) =>
    {
        if (System.Threading.Interlocked.Decrement(ref _CountDown) == 0)
            RaiseAllDoneEvent();
        else
            _Worker.RunWorkerAsync();
    };
    _Worker.RunWorkerAsync();
}
```

With Parallel I do somethign like this:

```
List<Item> _Items = GetItems();
int _CountDown = _Items.Count;
System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ForEach(_Items, (i) =>
{
    DoSomething(i);
    if (System.Threading.Interlocked.Decrement(ref _CountDown) == 0)
        RaiseAllDoneEvent();
});
```

My real question is: **is Interlocked.Decrement() correct here?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Parallel.ForEach will block until all of the items are processed- the right thing to do here seems to be to call RaiseAllDoneEvent() from the caller, immediately after calling Parallel.ForEach:

```
List<Item> _Items = GetItems();
System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ForEach(_Items, (i) =>
{
    DoSomething(i);
});
RaiseAllDoneEvent();
```

In other words, no need to count down (or keep track of how many items there are to process) at all.  If you want the parallel operations to not block, you can turn it into a bunch of tasks:

```
List<Item> _Items = GetItems();
Task.Factory.StartNew(()=> { 
        Task.WaitAll(
            _Items.Select(i => Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DoSomething(i))).ToArray()
        ); 
    }).ContinueWith(t => RaiseAllDoneEvent());
```

In that case, you'd be starting an outer task to spin up and then wait on a bunch of tasks (one for each item), and then finally raise the all done event.  None of this will block the original caller.

Comment: Is there an async option that leverages Parallel?

Comment: Tasks created using Task.Factory.StartNew are the equivalent of your original BackgroundWorker- they are always run on a background thread.  The benefit of Tasks is that if you spin up thousands of them, they are not going to choke your machine with N many threads.  They use thread pooling and work stealing to efficiently spread the work out amongst threads while hiding the complexity of doing that.

Comment: From me to you: all-on-one-line isn't always super easy to read. But I got it. Thanks again.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I was just trying to knock it out quickly for you :-)  I'll try to reformat later.